# How do I detect whether a process is currently dumping core?

Tags: linux

I am writing a support capture script that bundles all the cores and logs on the system pertaining to a few of my processes. In the event one of the processes is in the middle of dumping core, it will result in my support capture bundling a half-written core.

In order to help prevent user-error, I want to be able to detect whether the process is dumping core. The best I have come up with are two hacks:

(a) Query the size of the cores, in my core directory for 30 seconds, and see if any of them are changing size. If they are, a core is being dumped.

(b) Combining pgrep  and ps -l , see if the process has a WCHAN state of pipe_w

Is there a more elegant and full proof way to do this?

Is there perhaps something that can be queried that would tell us that *something* is dumping core?

Comment: If your application is dumping core often enough that your script catching it in the act is an issue, I think you have bigger problems than dealing with an occasional truncated core file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lsof` command will list currently open files and the processes that have handles to them. You can also instruct it to list only a single file. So in your case, you can use:

```
lsof "[absolute path to core file]"
```

(The double quotes are important in case the file path contains spaces.)

If the file is open, lsof will exit with zero.